# Can I count my JSON properties without any loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, counting

I have this question. I have a thousands of data with different properties, and I need to put their properties and how many those properties repeated. Ex;

```
0:[
  variants:{
    "color":"blue"
    "size":"3"
  }
]
1:[
   variants:{
     "color":"blue"
     "size":"2"
    }
  ]
2:[
  variants:{
    "color":"red"
    "size":"2"
  }
]


color=>blue (2)
color=>red (1)

size=>2(2)
size=>3(1)
```

but obviously with thousands of data.

If I count it with loop, does the performance will be affected?. Can I count it without any loop?. Another thing is that I have 500 instead 2 properties (color and size).

Comment: Thats not valid json

Comment: *does the performance will be affected?* In relation to what? A simple for-loop over 500 items will take milliseconds at worst

Comment: In relation of over 100,000 products with more than 500 items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count these properties you will have to iterate over the whole object. You can not check every property of this object without iterating the whole object. Even if you use something that does not seem like a loop, like a `for` statement would, it will still iterate the whole object, so not very much you can do for performance. You can use some built in iterator or maybe [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#forEach) to do it if you don't want to use a loop directly.